# How can I find always the same include file from within different sub folders

Tags: asciidoc

I want to include a adoc file from within different other adoc files. But the path to the include file depends from the deep of the directory structure. My Idea would be defining an environment variable to define the root of the structure. eg. something like this

```
include::${MY_ROOT_DIR}/.inc/include.adoc[]
```

Writing a fix absolute path is no option, I use the directory from linux windows and other different pcs.

But there are no env variables as far as I could google. And $MY_ROOT_DIR etc. does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asciidoc markup doesn't do path manipulation for you. When you set an attribute, it is a string value. When you include an attribute in an `include`, it is used as-is.

The `include` preprocessor directive's file resolution is described properly in [the documentation](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/include/#include-resolution).

The TL;DR: when you use `include` in an Asciidoc file, a relative path is resolved relative to the including file, whether it is the top-level file or an included file.

Your only solution is to use an absolute path.

If you want to use the attribute `MY_ROOT_DIR`, you can set it on the command line:

```
asciidoctor -a MY_ROOT_DIR=`pwd` file.adoc
```

The backticks mean that the `pwd` command is executed and its output is returned as a string value. So, `MY_ROOT_DIR` is set to the current directory.

For Windows, you would change the invocation to this:

```
asciidoctor -a MY_ROOT_DIR=%cd% file.adoc
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but here it is.

If you use the https://github.com/verhas/jamal preprocessor with Asciidoc, you can use it to perform the includes. The `include` macro in this preprocessor has a `[top]` option, which will include a file from within an already included file if it was included from the main file.

Also, there is a macro to get the value of an environment variable. This, however, is functionally equivalent and simpler with Asciidoctor solution depicted by @eskwayrd, using the `-a` attribute setting.

disclaimer: I created Jamal.

Answer (score 0):

I find a better way: If you want to include eg. a template file from anywhere in your project you need a file in your root called ".asciidoctorconfig"
where you put the following line:

:root: {asciidoctorconfigdir}

Then you can use it in your asciidoc files:

include::{root}/myPathFromRoot/myFile.adoc[]